# Codeigniter unable to read cookie

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies

I can set the cookie like this:

```
$cookie = array(
    'name'   => 'token',
    'value'  => $some_value,
    'expire' => '86500',
    'domain' => '192.168.1.11',
    'path'   => '/appfolder',
    'prefix' => '',
    'secure' => TRUE
);
$this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
```

it's there (I can see in Firefox settings).

But i can't read it. This is the code in my controller:

```
$this->load->helper('cookie');
$token = get_cookie('token', false);       //Same if TRUE
//$this->input->cookie('cookie_name', TRUE);   //also does not work
var_dump($token);
```

var_dump outputs bool(false).

Comment: Read the documentation, cookies are accessed through the Input Class, see <http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html>

Comment: yes.. but it's also not working

Comment: What is the value of `$cookie`

Comment: I edited the quesetion, but that's irrelevant, right? Cookie has been properly set as I see it in my web browser's settings..

Comment: Are you accessing the site at `http://192.168.1.11/appfolder` ?

Comment: Can i See your config file

Comment: my config.php file: http://pastebin.com/KnE1qQyV

Comment: maybe the problem with prefix

Answer (score 0):

First check your `config.php` cookie settings.If they are set wrong, cookies won't work

On the other hand, CI built in function has some problem which writes the cookie. you can change it by this way:
use `setcookie` function to set cookie `setcookie($name,$value,$expire,$path);` 
 and getting it back through `$this->input->cookie('user',TRUE);`

Have a look here http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html

Comment: with setcookie, I can't even set the cookie. that worked with $this->input->set_cookie()

Comment: try with this:
$cookie_data = get_cookie('token');

$token_value = $cookie_data['value'];

Comment: The cookie_data object is False (or 0) so I get NULL when I try to access property of a non object ($cookie_data['value'])

Answer (score 0):

```
 setcookie ( 'token' , $some_value , 86500, '/appfolder' , '192.168.1.11', FALSE );
```

Comment: There's no line for 'cookie_httponly' settings... should I add it?

Comment: nope its fine if its not just added in case if that's the problem..what is `cookie_prefix` ?

Comment: I tried everything, but still no success.. This is really stupid... damn you codeigniter! :(

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: make `'secure' => FALSE` edited my answer..check if this works

Comment: How are you checking it?  You won’t be able to read a cookie until the next page reload.  If you set it and immediately try to read it it won’t work.

Comment: I have 'secure' set to FALSE. About the page reload I know... I set cookie in a different controllers function than I read it... so it's not in the same page load...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38538/discussion-between-plain-jane-and-user568021)